# Loop through array and compare consecutive elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

Here is a simple Python program that outputs changes in value of consecutive elements:

```
amounts = [10, 9, 10, 3, 100, 100, 90, 80, 10, 30, 10]
for i in range(0, len(amounts)-1):
  if amounts[i+1] > amounts[i]:
    print("up", amounts[i+1]-amounts[i])
  elif amounts[i+1] < amounts[i]:
    print("down", amounts[i]-amounts[i+1])
  else:
    print("stay")
```

The following Ruby code is my first attempt at translating the above from Python:

```
amounts = [10, 9, 10, 3, 100, 100, 90, 80, 10, 30, 10]
for i in 0..(amounts.count)-1 do
  if amounts.at(i+1) > amounts.at(i)
    printf "up %d", (amounts.at(i+1)-amounts.at(i))
    if amounts.at(i+1) < amounts.at(i)
      printf "down %d", (amounts.at(i)-amounts.at(i+1))
    end
  else
    print "stay"
  end
end
```

This Ruby code returns NoMethodError as it is. If anyone could enlighten me as to the magical ways of Ruby, I would be very pleased.

Comment: Does this even work in Python ? You’re accessing an out of range index of amounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a "direct" translation of the python code to ruby - note that the syntax is *almost identical*! (The only subtle differences are `elif` vs `elsif` and the `print`/`puts` syntax.)

```
amounts = [10, 9, 10, 3, 100, 100, 90, 80, 10, 30, 10]
for i in 0..(amounts.count)-2 do
  if amounts[i+1] > amounts[i]
    puts "up #{amounts[i+1]-amounts[i]}"
  elsif amounts[i+1] < amounts[i]
    puts "down #{amounts[i]-amounts[i+1]}"
  else
    puts "stay"
  end
end
```

There was nothing wrong with using [`Array#at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-at), but it's just an alias for `Array#[]`. So if your question is about "translating" the code, then I don't see the point in making changes-for-the-sake-of-changes.

Note that I also *fixed* the off-by-one error that's present in both versions of your code -- you can only run this up to `len(amounts)-2`, not `len(amounts)-1`, or you'll go out of bounds!

However, this is not really written in "the ruby way". `for` loops are rarely used in ruby, because the language has other highly expressive iterators. Here is how I would have written it, using [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
amounts = [10, 9, 10, 3, 100, 100, 90, 80, 10, 30, 10]
amounts.each_cons(2) do |first, second|
  if first < second 
    puts "up #{second - first}"
  elsif first > second
    puts "down #{first - second}"
  else
    puts "stay"
  end
end

# Output:
down 1
up 1
down 7
up 97
stay
down 10
down 10
down 70
up 20
down 20
```

One advantage to this syntax is that off-by-one errors (like you had in the python!) aren't really possible, because you're just saying "loop over all elements" without having to worry about tracking the indexes yourself.

This is actually a really good example for appreciating the *elegance* of ruby, if code is written in "the ruby way" rather than merely a direct translation.

Comment: Note that for "simple" iterations in ruby, it would be common to use methods like `each` or `map`, rather than a `for` loop. Like I said, that method is very rarely the "best" way of writing it in ruby.

Comment: I understand that for loop is not really the best in Ruby (apparently, you Ruby guys really are a superior breed) but as you said, I am just looking for a simple "direct" translation from Python for now in order to facilitate my learning. I want to become a Ruby expert. I really do have an appreciation for the elegance of Ruby. There are plenty of things a Python pleb like me would not yet know.

Comment: Didn't mean to come off as snobbish, sorry! I only wanted to emphasise that translating the code "as directly as possible" might only involve some tiny syntax changes like `elif --> elsif`, but you don't really gain full benefits from doing that. The converse is also true, of course -- Python has excellent list comprehension syntax, for example, that you could easily miss out on by making a "dumb" direct translation of ruby --> python!

Answer (score 0):

You could also employ an enumerator.

```
amounts = [10, 9, 10, 3, 100, 100, 90, 80, 10, 30, 10]
```

```
enum = amounts.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [10, 9, 10, 3, 100, 100, 90, 80, 10, 30, 10]:each>
loop do
  diff = -enum.next + enum.peek
  puts case diff <=> 0
  when -1 then "down #{-diff}"
  when  0 then "stay"
  else         "up #{diff}"
  end
end
```

```
down 1
up 1
down 7
up 97
stay
down 10
down 10
down 70
up 20
down 20
```

See [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each) (or use [Object#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum)), [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next), [Enumerator#peek](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) and [Integer#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (the last referred to as the *spaceship* operator).

As explained by the docs, when `peek` is executed after `next` has caused `enum` to generate its last element a `StopIteration` exception is raised which `loop` handles by breaking out of the loop.